# SSIS How to import xml elements into table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am using XML source in SSIS to import XML file into SQL Server database.

I am not using all detail elements from XML file. But I want to save original element with all details in case they are needed at some point in future.

Lets say xml:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <desc>Some row</desc>
    <child>
      <hi>hi</hi>
      <ho>ho</ho>
    </child>
  </row>
  <row>
    <desc>Some row2</desc>
    <child>
      <hi>hi2</hi>
      <ho>ho2</ho>
    </child>
  </row>
</root>
```

Intended result in structure:

```
Create Table ParentTable
(
    Id int primary key identity,
    [desc] nvarchar(50),
    xmlElement xml
)
```

How can I load original XML element (in this case element "row") into database as well by using SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new in SSIS, but in internet found solution (maybe not the best but worked).

So here it comes.

1. First i create same table as you provided **ParentTable**, just changed **desc** to 255. Also added Connection Manager to package.
2. Created two new variables `User::FileName = "some.xml"` and `User::SourceCatalog = "C:\xmlCatalog\"`
3. Then added **Data Flow Task** in which I added **Script Component** (selected Source type).
4. Opened **Script Transformation Editor** in **Script** tab into **ReadOnlyVariables** property added newly created variables `User::FileName,User::SourceCatalog`.
5. In the tab **Inputs and Outputs** renamed **Output 0** to **XMLResultOutput** and under **Output Columns** created two new columns **xmlDesc** (Data Type = Unicode string [DT_WSTR] 255) and **xmlData** (Data Type = Unicode string [DT_WSTR] 3000). This variables will be used later in C# script.

[image: inputs and outputs]

6. Pressed **Edit Script...** in the **Script** tab. In the opened window in the CreateNewOutputRows method paste this code:

   ```
   XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

   string xml_filepath = Variables.SourceCatalog + Variables.FileName;
   xDoc.Load(xml_filepath);

   foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("//row"))
   {

       this.XMLResultOutputBuffer.AddRow();

       this.XMLResultOutputBuffer.xmlData = xNode.OuterXml.ToString();

       this.XMLResultOutputBuffer.xmlDesc = xNode.SelectSingleNode("./desc").InnerText;//xNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;

   }
   ```

   Don't forget to add `using System.Xml;`
7. Added **OLE DB Destination** component, linked **Script Component** to it, selected table, mapped columns and THATS IT.